# What is the most efficient way to wait for a page element (xpath) to show up in Selenium Webdriver with Python?

Tags: python, class, selenium-webdriver, wait

What is the most efficient way to wait for a page element (xpath) to show up in Selenium Webdriver with Python?

webdriver wait until, how do you use it when waiting for a class type to appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe Selenium has inbuild methods to check if an element is enabled or displayed.
Try to play around with

`elem.is_enabled` and
`elem.is_displayed`

Otherwise, you can use a while loop with a try/catch:

```py
while True:
    try:
        elem = driver.find_by....
        break
    except:
        time.sleep(1)
```

In this case, the script will only proceed when the element is found

:)